# Grails/GORM not cascading save through entire object hierarchy

Tags: grails, grails-orm, cascade

I'm having trouble getting saves cascaded down my object hierarchy.  Below is the code of my object hierarchy.

```
class Entity {
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
}

class Attribute extends ValuePossessor {
    static belongsTo = Entity
}

abstract class ValuePossessor {
    def valueService
    Value value
    void setValue(val) {
        this.value = valueService.Create(val)
        this.value.possessor = this
    }
}

abstract class Value {
    static belongsTo = [possessor: ValuePossessor]
}

class StringValue extends Value {
    String value
}
```

The valueService is simply a service with a big switch statement that creates the correct value type (string, boolean, int, etc.).

```
Entity e = new Entity()
Attribute attr = new Attribute()
attr.setValue(1)
e.addToAttributes(attr)
e.save()
```

The above code correctly creates all objects, but fails to save the value object.  The entity and attribute are saved, but the value is not.  Am I missing some identifier needed to cascade all the way down to the value object?

Comment: Since Value belongs to ValueProcessor and you're not setting processor.value that could be the reason.  
Try println e.errors after saving to see if there's some validation error.

Comment: I am setting processor.value in the setValue method, and I have it configured to fail on validation errors.  It does not fail, just simply doesn't save the value.

Comment: Hard to say, when you get away from Grails conventions it can be tough to debug

Comment: @James: What do you mean?  Is there a more "Grailsy" way to do this?  I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I would start with forgoing abstract classes. Domain classes are meant to map to tables, so the simpler the better.

Comment: The abstract class Value allows me to have several type-specific classes (StringValue, BooleanValue, IntValue, etc.) yet still be able to store them in a single property.  Without them, the code gets very messy because each type would need its own property inside the containing class.  I just attempted to do this using an interface instead and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  Apparently there is some magic in the grails dynamic setters.  I changed the `setValue(val)` method to `set(val)` and it started working.  Lesson learned: don't override grails' dynamically added methods because they are built with magic, pixy dust, and unicorn urine.